# What does np.array [5, :] mean

Tags: python, numpy

In the following Python syntax for the numpy library, what does the `:` token mean?

```
some_array [5, :]
```

Comment: The `:` creates a `slice`.  Ever used `alist[2:10:2]`?  Syntactically the same thing.  The actual call passes a tuple to the array indexer: `some_array.__getitem__((5, slice(None)))`

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. If you want to understand simple examples with a library, it is best to start with the documentation or tutorials for that library, or by [searching the Internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=numpy+colon).

Comment: With all due respect, I couldn't have known the keyword column from the syntax I gave you. I had a supposition, and wanted to check that back, while engaging with the community.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you've given, this would refer to the fifth row of `some_array` (assuming it's a NumPy array).

Comment: Yes, it's a numpy array. Why wouldn't you just write some_array [5] then?

Comment: Either works in this case. The notation you've described becomes useful if you want to access a column rather than a row / want every element along a given axis (e.g. a valid slice for a 3D array might look like `some_array[:,2]`, which gets the third column of a 2D array).

Comment: Ok, perfetto, thank you!